# While using npm start in cmd node js to start the lite server, its throwing an error

Tags: node.js, json

It's showing there is an error in the line 226 of the package.json file. I have also tried adding commas in the code but its not working.
This is the note I am getting.
Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

[Cmd error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtcIE.png)

[Line 226](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tctpi.png)

[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqdA6.png)

Comment: Position 226 != Line 226. The error shows a snipped of your broken code, search for it.

Comment: there are more than thousands line in the json file, can you please say how can I search for it?

Comment: CTRL+F, for example.

Comment: I have added a picture please have a look at it.

Comment: End of “test” line needs a comma and remove comma from the lite script line

Comment: Did you try add comma on line 9 on package.json-> scripts?

Comment: Thank You , but this is the error I am getting now.  Unexpected token "}" (0x7D) in JSON at position 251 while parsing near "...e\":\"lite-server\",\n  },\n  \"author\": \